# google maps your timeline api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

google maps' new feature your timeline https://www.google.com/maps/timeline seems to be useful to retrieve location history for a given user, my question is
how to use google maps to retrieve this timeline ?
it is possible ?
sorry am new to google world and i have looked for this information on their site but no news.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you found something about timeline api?

Comment: no, i think there s no specific api

Comment: Any update? I'm not super confident about processing the JSON as the answer suggests (I'd like to know how many times I visited a certain place in the last year).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

No. There isn't an API, this time, to get data from the timeline, but the data can be access from takeout by the user. So the only thing you can do is request from the user to upload the JSON(or KML) file of the data.

You can put in your site a url like this:
https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout/custom/location_history
and tell to user to download the json file and upload it.

Comment: Thanks man! This link is super useful und pretty much the same like an API. And it gives the user a more transparency from where the data comes. And for me it's good that there is no API, the collected data is too sensible.